# scope of 3 dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d

I'm trying to create a 3 dimensional array dynamicall in javascript based on a flat array of objects. after looping through the array, the array seems empty. If I print while in the loop, it seems to work, but then it seems to be gone and I want to return this to the caller. Help ?

```
//init the 3d array ??
this.teams = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sportsStandings.length; i++) {
  var item = sportsStandings[i];
  if(!this.teams[item.league]) 
    this.teams[item.league] = new Array();

  if(!this.teams[item.league][item.division])
    this.teams[item.league][item.division] = new Array();

  this.teams[item.league][item.division][this.teams[item.league][item.division].length] 
    = new Team(item.teamName, item.wins, item.losses);

  console.log(this.teams); //this prints properly, and i see the 3d array grow
}
console.log('second' + this.teams); //this prints nothing
```

Comment: If those "league", "division", etc. properties are not numbers, then you're not really building an array, you're building an object with properties. JavaScript array behavior applies only to numerically-indexed properties. What exactly is in that "sportsStandings" array?

Comment: Also, `console.log` has different print formatting behaviors across browsers. Try using a comma instead of a `+`

Comment: Store `sportsStandings[i]` into a variable and reference that variable, it will help with performance and make it easier to read.

Comment: sportsStandings is a response object from a mongoose find call. The printing is working fine, the +/, is not an issue. The last print of the loop shows:

    [ al: [ east: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    central: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    west: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ],
  nl: [ west: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    east: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    central: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] ]

while the one outside shows:
second

Comment: @Pointy - if that were the case why would the print in the loop work ? In any event, I just need to later get to loop over those items later in my front end....
    for(leagues) for(divisions) for(teams)
is there a better way then a 3d array ?

Comment: OK, so if those things are strings and not numbers, then you don't need arrays at all; you've got an object, not an array.  The reason your outer `console.log()` doesn't work is that the `+` operation converts your object to a string first. Change it to `console.log("second"); console.log(this.teams);` to see.

Comment: To put it another way, when you add an "al" property to the outer "teams" object, you are not changing the length of that array at all.  The length of an array only includes the numerically-indexed properties.  Adding "al" and "nl" properties will still leave you with a zero-length array, in other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up the code a bit, there is a couple of other ways to write it.

```
this.teams = [];
var teams = this.teams;
for(var i = 0; i < sportsStandings.length; i++) {

    var ss = sportsStandings[i],
        league = ss.league,
        division = ss.division,
        teamName = ss.teamName,
        wins = ss.wins,
        losses = ss.losses;

    if (!teams[league]) {
        teams[league] = {};
        teams[league][division] = [];
    } else if (!teams[league][division]) {
        teams[league][division] = [];
    }

    var newTeam = new Team(teamName, wins, losses);
    teams[league][division].push(newTeam);
}
```

Comment: wow... thanks. that works. the big difference seems to be the push. Can you explain why that is ?

Comment: The thing is, the "teams" array will have length 0 when it's all done, because the properties made from "league" will not affect the length.  The "teams" variable should probably be initialized with `{}` instead of `[]` in other words.

Comment: ah! yes. I see. There's a difference between the array and properties that I'm missing. Doing this seems to clear it up. Muchas Gracias..